# Strange error checking if directory exists with Bash script

Tags: bash

Here's a bash script I'm working on:

```
dir="~/path/to/$1/folder"

if [ -d "$dir" ]; then
    # do some stuff
else
    echo "Directory $dir doesn't exist";
    exit 1
fi
```

and when I run it from the terminal:

```
> ./myscript.sh 123
Directory ~/path/to/123/folder doesn't exist
```

But that folder clearly does exist. This works normally:

```
> ls ~/path/to/123/folder
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
dir="$HOME/path/to/$1/folder"
```

Comment: Just because Joakim provided no explanation at all: You had quoted the ~.  ~ only expands in bash during tilde expansion, but anything that you quote, you disable the special meaning of, so the tilde (~) no longer meant "expands to the home directory of the current user".  It just meant: "the directory in the current directory called ~".  Which didn't exist, hence the error.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that bash performs tilde expansion before shell parameter substitution, so after it substitutes `~/path/to/folder` for `$dir`, it doesn't try to expand the `~`, so it looks for a directory literally named with a tilde in it, which of course doesn't exist.  See [section 3.5 of the bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions) for a more detailed explanation on bash's expansions.